# How to save state to localStorage and read it again when the page is reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Can someone help me save a toggled class in localstorage so that every time I reload the the page the toggled class will still be there.

```js
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function() {
  $('#down-right').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right');

  if (window.localStorage.toggled != "fa-chevron-down") {
    $('#down-right').toggleClass("fa-chevron-down", true);
    window.localStorage.toggled = "fa-chevron-down";
  } else {
    $('#down-right').toggleClass("fa-chevron-right", false);
    window.localStorage.toggled = "fa-chevron-right";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store state in localStorage

`localStorage.setItem('state',state)  // for storing`

> Read On Page reload

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    const state = localStorage.getItem("state");  // for retrieving
}

window.onload = function(e){ 
    const state = localStorage.getItem("state");  // for retrieving
}
```